# Have User be able to Swipe Down on temporary UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I wanted to be able to have the user swipe down to dismiss a temporary Notification that comes in from the bottom.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
func showAnimationToast(...) {
    
        let toastView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: view.frame.size.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, width: view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 60))
        ...
        toastView.tag = 1474
        
        let animationView = AnimationView(name: animationName)
        ...
        toastView.addSubview(animationView)
        
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: toastView.frame.size.height, y: 5, width: toastView.frame.size.width - toastView.frame.size.height, height: 50))
        ...
        toastView.addSubview(messageLabel) 
        toastView.isUserInteractionAvailable = true
```

I tried to add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to `toastView`, but it never worked. I even tried the simple UITapGestureRecognizer and it STILL didn't work.

Here's what I tried:

```
        //Let Swipe Down Dismiss. Does not work
        let swipeDownGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissToast(_:)))
        swipeDownGesture.direction = .down
        toastView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDownGesture)
        
        //Show animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, animations: {
            toastView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom - 70
        }, completion: {_ in
            animationView.play()
        })
        
        //Remove after specified time
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: duration, animations: {
            toastView.center.y = self.view.frame.size.height + 50
        }, completion: {_ in
            toastView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
    
    @objc func dismissToast(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("dismiss")
        let toastView = view.subviews.filter { view in
            if view.tag == 1474 /*toastView*/ tag{
                return true
            }
            return false
        }.last!
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, animations: {
            toastView.center.y = self.view.frame.size.height + 50
        }, completion: {_ in
            toastView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
        
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What exactly happened?

Comment: It simply doesn't even call the function/selector

Comment: Did you set `toastView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`? Please show a [mcve]. Don't omit everything with `...`.

Comment: mmm ok sorry about that, I just didn't wanna put a block of code that'll scare people off. Yes, I did add toastView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true. I will edit that in. Other than that, all the `...` are just customizing the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that while a view is waiting for an animation to play (during the "delay" period), it can't receive user interactions.

One way to work around this is to not use the `delay` parameter, and instead use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        toastView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom - 70
    }, completion: {_ in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration + 0.2) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, animations: {
                toastView.center.y = self.view.frame.size.height + 50
            }, completion: {_ in
                toastView.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }

    })
```